# Manipulating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

I have come across this in a solution for a BMO problem where you have to find $a_{2013}$ for:

$a_n$ = $\frac{n+1}{n-1}$($a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1}$)

where $a_1$ = 1. It says that you manipulate it to get $a_n$ = $\frac {2(n+1)a_{n-1}}{n}$

However, I have no clue how he came to this. I know that you can change $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1}$ to $\frac{(n-1)(1 + a_{n-1})}{2}$ which will give you:

$a_n = \frac{(n+1)(1 + a_{n-1})}{2}$

...but I am not sure where to go from there. Thanks, Sam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Rearranging the recurrence relation gives:

$$\frac{n-1}{n+1}a_{n}=a_1+a_2+...a_{n-1}.$$

Substituting $n-1$ for $n$ gives:

$$\frac{n-2}{n}a_{n-1}=a_1+a_2+...a_{n-2}.$$

Now subtract the equations to get:

$$\frac{n-1}{n+1}a_{n}-\frac{n-2}{n}a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I think I can work from here. When it comes to olympiad style problems do you know how I can get better at knowing how to rearrange such a relationship?

Comment: @SamuelBird Oh my, I really don't know what to suggest other than practice practice practice. I know that's not much of an answer, but when it comes to recognizing patterns I honestly can't think of a better one.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that was the answer but just wanted to make sure I am not being silly. I better get on then. :)